# How do you calculate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan(x)\ln(\sin(x))\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to calculate
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan(x)\ln(\sin(x))\,dx.
$$

I tried taking $\cos x$ as $t$ and converting the whole expression in $t$ and then integrating by parts. That didn't help. Integrating by parts directly also doesn't help. I'm guessing there must be a different, better approach to solve this.

Can someone help?

Comment: Never mind... This is the derivative of the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in [disguise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals). The final result is $-\dfrac{\pi^2}{24}$

Comment: Confusing, could you please update your question with the actual integral you want to calculate?

Comment: I didn't quite get that beta function answer. Is there any way to do it besides that? This is a question given in the book provided by my coaching institute where we haven't yet been taught Beta functions. So there must be another way of doing it. Although yeah, the answer is correct. As for the king property, yes. That doesn't help either.

Comment: @mickep, this is the actual integral. I didn't get here using some substitution. As in, this IS the question given.

Comment: If instead of $\tan(x)$, $\cot(x)$ would have been there, the integral could have been solved within seconds.

Comment: Lol, yeah. Wouldn't have been much of a question then.

Comment: Are you sure **this** is the question?

Comment: Yeah, since the answer given is - pi^2/4 and it's the value of **this** integral..

Comment: Lets wait for @juantheron.

Comment: @Lucian can you please elaborate on you answer. It would be really helpful for me if I could link this integral with the beta function somehow

Comment: @SoLo: Write $\ln(\sin x)=\bigg[\dfrac d{dk}\Big(\sin^kx\Big)\bigg]_{k=0}$ and then employ the relation between [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals) and the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
I&=\int^{\frac\pi2}_0\tan(x)\ln(\sin(x))dx
\\
&=\int_{0}^1\frac{\ln(\sqrt{1-t^2})}tdt\tag{$t=\cos{x}$}
\\
&=\int_{0}^1\frac{y\ln y}{1-y^2}\:dy\tag{$y=\sqrt{1-t^2}$}
\\
&=\int_{0}^1y\ln y\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y^{2n}\right)dy
\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^1y^{2n+1}\ln y\:dy\tag1
\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{(2n+2)^2}
\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}{24}
\end{align}
Note in $(1)$
$$
\int_{0}^1y^{2n+1}\ln y\:dy=\frac{y^{2n+2}\ln y}{2n+2}\bigg |_0^1-\frac1{2n+2}\int_{0}^1y^{2n+1}\:dy=-\frac1{(2n+2)^2}
$$

Comment: How did you introduce summation?

Comment: By taylor series of $\frac1{1-y^2}$

Comment: I do, and this infact is a better solution for school purposes. If nothing else, I'll accept this answer. I'll wait for a different method for a while though.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$I=\int^{\frac\pi2}_0\tan(x)\ln(\sin(x))dx$$
Put $\cos x=t; -\sin xdx=dt$ 
$$=-\int^{0}_1\frac{\ln(\sqrt{1-t^2})}tdt$$
$$=\frac12\int^1_0\frac{2t\ln(\sqrt{1-t^2})}{t^2}dt$$
Put $1-t^2=u;-2tdt=du$ $$\frac12\int^1_0\frac{\ln(\sqrt u)}{u-1}du$$
$$\frac12\int^1_0\frac{\ln(\sqrt u)}{u-1}du=\frac12[-\frac{\text{Li}_2(1-u)}{2}]^1_0=-\frac{\pi^2}{24}$$

Comment: Doesn't help. In the second integral, you again get integration of log..

Comment: One minute, updating.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your question.

Comment: No, there isn't. Lucian got the correct answer to this question, albeit using a method that we can't use/hasn't been taught to us..

Comment: See my edit then. I said that there was a typo because I don't think you can simplify it using elementary functions.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I'm still looking for a way to solve it using elementary functions though.

Comment: BTW learn polylogarithms, they are fun.

Comment: Yeah, I'll look them up. They seem interesting.

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't help. :(