# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x\ln{\cos(x)}}{\tan x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

I'm confronted with a problem: prove that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x\ln{\cos(x)}}{\tan x}dx=-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln^22$

I've already known $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x}{\tan x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2\ $ and $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln{\cos(x)}dx=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2\ $(which are actually 
equivalent to each other)

But they're not sufficient to solve this, I guess.

Comment: From where did you got this problem? As a hint, try to integrate by parts.

Comment: You may compute the Fourier cosine series of $\frac{x}{\tan x}$, recall the Fourier cosine series of $\log\cos(x)$ from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos) (they are related to each other via integration by parts) and exploit Plancherel's theorem.

Comment: I knew I did it before. This is a duplicate of [Integral: $\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{Li}_2(x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226042/integral-int-01-frac-mathrmli-2x2-sqrt1-x2dx).

Comment: @カカロット Thanks for your link. I got this problem from a infinite integral and I used trigonometric substitution.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for all the commentators. I solved this problem with the help of relevant links, but slightly different from them.

First, integrate by parts

$\begin{align} I&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x\ln{(\cos x)}}{\tan x}dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\ln{(\cos x)}d(\ln(\sin x))\\ &=x\ln{(\cos x)}\ln(\sin x)\left|_{0}^{\pi/2}\right.-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln{(\sin x)}d(x\ln{(\cos x)})dx\\ &=-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln{(\sin x)}(\ln{(\cos x)}-x\tan x)dx\\ &=-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln{(\sin x)}\ln{(\cos x)}dx+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan x\ln{(\sin x)}dx-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\frac{\pi}{2}-x) \tan x\ln{(\sin x)}dx\\ &=-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln{(\sin x)}\ln{(\cos x)}dx+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan x\ln{(\sin x)}dx-I \end{align}$
then these two integrals can be solved as follows

$\displaystyle I_1=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln{(\sin x)}\ln{(\cos x)}dx=\frac{\pi}{2} \ln ^{2}(2)-\frac{\pi^{3}}{48}\ $ ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1311102/709065))

$\displaystyle I_2=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan x\ln{(\sin x)}dx=-\frac{\pi^2}{24}\ $([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1474418/709065))

therefore $\ I=\dfrac{-I_1+\dfrac{\pi}{2}I_2}{2}=-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\ln^2 (2)$